# Can you input the blockchain through remote web server?

Tags: blockchain, daemon

So I am trying to import the blockchain onto my VPS, however, my VPS has a low amount of storage.  I am hoping to import the blockchain using monero-blockchain-import, so is it possible to load this file from my website?
BTW, its at webminer.biz/downloads/blockchain.raw

P.S:  My Website host doesn't allow daemons, which is why I need to run it on another VPS.  If you know of a good web hosting site, feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use monero-blockchain-import to import a raw blockchain file, wherever it comes from, including from your own web server.

However, monero-blockchain-import does not support reading from the network directly, it must import from a file (and will make two passes over it, if memory serves).

One possibility is to temporarily mount a partition from your web server onto your VPS, maybe using sshfs.

In any case, do not turn verification off. Many people seem to be doing this for speed, which opens them up to being fed malicious blockchain data.